# Sending GUIDs over WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF project, it is connected to a database with Entity Framework.

I'm trying to send a list of objects and one of the variables is of type GUID.

I'm converting my `entity.Employees` to `List<Employees>` and if the `ID` is `int` everything works fine but if I change it to a `GUID`, it crashes with this error message:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to xxxxxxxxxxx:92389: service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Can anyone help?

Comment: 'It crashes' is not a sufficiently precise bug report. What was the error message? What were the input values?

Comment: The error Massage is:

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to xxxxxxxxxxx:92389:service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Comment: Based on the error message, it sounds like your service may have crashed due to an unhandled exception.  Post your code so you can get better answers.

Comment: in Isevice: [OperationContract]
        List<Employees> Employees();                                    in Service:                                                     public List<Employees> Employees()
        {
            List<Employees> Emp = new List<Employees>();
            using (ProjectEntities PE = new ProjectEntities())
            {
                Emp = PE.Employees.ToList();
            }
            return Emp;

        }

Comment: Employees.EmployeeID is GUID
if ill turn it in to INT or String its working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a solution:
if you want to avoid from casting your GUID to string you can just simply disable the proxy.
in your Entity code just add this:

```
YourContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false
```

But you need to know that if you will do this you will not able to make DML commands.

Hope its helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the GUID as `ToString()`. Will be easier.

And maybe you should take a look to [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I hope this helps

Comment: what attibutes should I try?

Comment: [DataContract] in the class, and [DataMember] in all the properties

Comment: Then the better solutions is to parse ToString(). I think that it could be the best to solve your problem

Comment: The link above goes to Spanish version of the MSDN page.
Here is the Original: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-generate the client proxy on your client as you have changed the type of a property in the data contract.